# How to check my WordPress.org site MySQL queries generating items?

Tags: plugins

My WordPress site generate hughes MySQL queries. As a result of that I got "Error establishing connection to database". I use a shared hosting. When I check error logs on my host (cpanel) it shows some plugins generate huge errors. When I'm asking it from that plugin developer, he mention that it should be your theme issue, because of that plugin not generate MySQL queries.

So how do I check all of my blog MySQL queries generating items (theme, plug in, etc)?

If those plugins generated errors as a result of my theme issues, can I fix them without changing theme?

I'm not familier with coding. :( .

Thanks!

Comment: Chris, how can someone here solve this when you haven't so much as named the plugins you are using, or your theme, or provided [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? You've called the mechanic, said "My car is broken", and asked "How do I fix it?". Please edit your question to provide as much detail as you can, starting with but not limited to the things I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Install WordPress Debug Bar plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/